# How to host multiple Facebook Apps using a single domain and SSL certificate

Tags: facebook, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

Good evening to all users of StackOverflow,
I would like to find help in a complex question now. Install applications on Facebook (Minisites in php, flash, html5, etc. ..) my question is:
I need only one domain with ssl certificate? or buy multiple certificates for each of the microsites?
Just this: https://www.nomedominio.com/esempio
or: https://esempio.nomedominio.com
Thanks for your help. Greetings Mimmo.

Comment: Please translate the subject line into English

Comment: Install more apps in a single domain ssl

Answer (score 4):

**If this is a facebook question:**

Just have all your sites under:

- nomedomino.com/site1
- nomedomino.com/site2
- nomedomino.com/site3

As facebook users will never see them in tabs.

We have ours under:
*example.com/fb-apps/app-name1* with a SSL on *example.com*

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have a SSL certificate for each of your microsites, or buy a so-called wildcard certificate that allows you to host all your microsites on one host mapped to *.nomedominio.com. The wildcard one is (of course) more expensive.

Comment: thanks for your help, so you only need one certificate for a domain is to install the mini-sites in separate folders? example:
www.dominio.com / Test 1
  www.dominio.com / Test 2
..... etc etc. ..???

Comment: For seperate folders no additional certificates are needed.